# How to get two arrays from mongo aggregate with $project and $map insdite ti

Tags: node.js, mongodb, project, aggregation

I have a nodejs app with Repository architecture. I am trying to get the data returned from an aggregation I made:

```
function foo(id) {
return await this.collection.aggregate([
      {
        "$match": {
          _id: "ObjectId('"+ id +"')"
        }
      },
      {
        "$addFields": {
          "self": "$$ROOT"
        }
      },
      {
        "$graphLookup": {
          "from": "categories",
          "startWith": "$_id",
          "connectFromField": "_id",
          "connectToField": "categoryId",
          "as": "categoryLookup"
        }
      },
      {
        "$addFields": {
          "categoryLookup": {
            "$concatArrays": [
              "$categoryLookup",
              [
                "$self"
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$lookup": {
          "from": "locos",
          "localField": "categoryLookup._id",
          "foreignField": "categoryId",
          "as": "locosLookup"
        }
      },
      {
        "$project": {
            categories: {
              "$map": {
                "input": "$categoryLookup",
                "as": "c",
                "in": "$$c._id"
              }
            },
            locos: {
              "$map": {
                "input": "$locosLookup",
                "as": "l",
                "in": "$$l._id"
              }
            }
        }
      }
    ]);
}
```

I want to get the data from the returned cursor which can not be transformed into an array. The problem is that this code works fine on the playground but I think also that $filed won't get the field since we need to use $getField { "fieldName": "field"}. I am really stuck here and the answers given to me previously weren't helping ..
the next step please

Comment: When awaiting the aggregation function, the result should be an array.  What does the raw result look like?

Comment: Can you share some sample data and expected output?